# Cocoa PDF page splitting

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf

In the application I'm creating, I load a long page of HTML into a webView and then print it to a PDF using the following:

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    if ([frame isEqual:[[self doc] mainFrame]]) 
    {
        NSMutableData *newData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        NSPrintInfo *newInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
        NSView *docView = [[[[self doc] mainFrame] frameView] documentView];

        NSPrintOperation *newPrintOp = [NSPrintOperation PDFOperationWithView:docView insideRect:docView.bounds toData:newData printInfo:newInfo];

        BOOL runPrint = [newPrintOp runOperation];  
        if (!runPrint)
        {
           NSLog(@"Print Failed");
        }
        PDFDocument *newDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:newData];
        [newData release];
        [self setPdf:newDoc];

        //Other code here
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I look at `newDoc`, it is a huge PDF of a single page. What I would prefer would be the printing acting the same as it does from the "save as PDF..." dialog - that is, splitting the PDF into multiple reasonably-sized pages.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

I attempted inserting the following after `NSPrintInfo *newInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];`

```
[newInfo setVerticalPagination:NSAutoPagination];
[newInfo setHorizontalPagination:NSAutoPagination];
```

NSAutoPagination is described in the docs as the following:

> NSAutoPagination
>   The image is divided into equal-sized rectangles and placed in one column of pages.
>   Available in Mac OS X v10.0 and later.
>   Declared in NSPrintInfo.h.

This had no effect on the printed PDF.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get a file with one large page because `+ PDFOperationWithView:` method doesn't support pagination at all. For that reason calling `- setVerticalPagination:` or `- setHoriziontalPagination:` doesn't change anything.

You could try use "classical" `+ printOperationWithView:printInfo:` method, configure it to save PDF to temporary location and then create `PDFDocument` with contents of obtained file. I hope that fragment of code below will help.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo] dictionary];
[dict setObject:NSPrintSaveJob forKey:NSPrintJobDisposition];
[dict setObject:temporaryFilePath forKey:NSPrintSavePath];
NSPrintInfo *pi = [[NSPrintInfo alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
[pi setHorizontalPagination:NSAutoPagination];
[pi setVerticalPagination:NSAutoPagination];

NSPrintOperation *op = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] printInfo:pi];
[pi release];
[op setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
[op setShowsProgressPanel:NO];

if ([op runOperation] ){
    PDFDocument *doc = [[[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: temporaryFilePath]] autorelease];
    // do with doc what you want, remove file, etc.
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! If no-one else comes up with an better answer in the next day, I'll award the bounty to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to be awake at by the bounty's end, so you win!

Comment: This is great. Is there any way to skip the temporary file and just get this into an NSData directly? I could get this into an NSData object by reading the file but I would like to skip this step if at all possible.

Comment: @Julian Probably best asked as a separate question referencing this one. From a brief glance at the docs, I don't see any way to do it. Although, unless you're dealing with a huge amount of data, I'm not sure how much reading the file in will cost...

Comment: @Daniel, I wanted to avoid a temporary file can of worms but I found an article in Cocoa With Love that showed me how to do it properly without leaving an unclean mess behind. So all is good.

Comment: @Julian - any chance you could post the link? :)

Comment: @JeremyMassel http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/temporary-files-and-folders-in-cocoa.html

Comment: Do you mind pasting all the code you used to make a PDF in one place for reference? I've been searching a lot and cant seem to find anything that properly makes a paginated PDF for Mac.

Comment: `NSPrintSavePath` is deprecated now. Docs say to use `NSPrintJobSavingURL`