# How do I draw a grid of images in Cocoa and export it to a PDF?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pdf, nsview

I'm making a tool that will pull data from a `.csv` and create a grid of images with captions [like "[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s30hO.png)"] in Cocoa, then export that to a PDF. I do not need to actually display the view, just save a file. As a complete beginner to drawing programmatically, I have some questions about the process:

- What class should I use? I'm assuming `NSView`, but like I said I've never done this before so I'm not sure.
- Do I need to specify the pixel coordinates for every single object, or can I make each object relative to another in some way?
- How do I create separate pages for the view?

Keep in mind that I read the Apple guides, and while it had some helpful tidbits, overall it was unusually hard for me to comprehend. If someone could explain in layman's terms what I need to know it would be very appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't you think you should read a book or more about Objective-C programming before asking specific questions?

Comment: I actually have read a book about Objective-C, but that didn't cover Cocoa very much. I plan to read up on Cocoa too but I have a friend who needs my program within two weeks from now. That's the main reason why I'm asking—I've been programming for nearly 4 years; I could eventually learn how to do this on my own but I don't have enough free time to do so before June.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out a few days ago, thought I'd come back to answer for anyone else with the same question.

> What class should I use? I'm assuming `NSView`, but like I said I've never done this before so I'm not sure.

`NSView` is in fact the class I used to draw each page.

> Do I need to specify the pixel coordinates for every single object, or can I make each object relative to another in some way?

I did end up specifying the pixel coordinates for each image on the grid (plus its caption), but it was easy to calculate where they should be placed once I learned the size of a 8.50 x 11 inch page in points. The next challenge was drawing them in a `for` loop rather than having to explicitly declare each possible `NSRect`. Here's my code in `drawRect`:

```
// Declared elsewhere: constants for horizontal/vertical spacing,
// the width/height for an image, and a value for what row the image
// should be drawn on
for (int i = 0; i < [_people count]; i++) {
    float horizontalPoint = 0.0; // What column should the image be in?

    if (i % 2 != 0) { // Is i odd? (i.e. Should the image be in the right column?)
        horizontalPoint += (imageWidth + horizontalSpace); // Push it to the right
    }

    NSRect imageRect = NSMakeRect(horizontalSpace + horizontalPoint, verticalSpace + verticalPoint,
                              imageWidth, imageHeight);

    // Draw the image with imageRect

    if (i % 2 != 0) { // Is i odd? (i.e. Is the current row drawn?)
        verticalPoint = (imageRect.origin.y + imageRect.size.height); // Push the row down
    }
}
```

I do realize that I could've coded that more efficiently (e.g. making a `BOOL` for `i % 2 != 0`), but I was rushing the whole project because my friend who needed it was on a deadline.

> How do I create separate pages for the view?

With some googling, I came up with [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8962592). However, this wasn't going to work unless I had one big view with all the pages concatenated together. I came up with a way to do just that:

```
// Get an array of arrays containing 1-6 JANPerson objects each using data from a parsed in .csv
NSArray *paginatedPeople = [JANGridView paginatedPeople:people];
int pages = [JANGridView numberOfPages:people];

// Create a custom JANFlippedView (just an NSView subclass overriding isFlipped to YES)
// This will hold all of our pages, so the height should be the # of pages * the size of one page
JANFlippedView *view = [[JANFlippedView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 612, 792 * pages)];

for (int i = 0; i < [paginatedPeople count]; i++) { // Iterate through each page
    // Create a custom JANGridView with an array of people to draw on a grid
    JANGridView *gridView = [[JANGridView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 612, 792) people:paginatedPeople[i]];

    // Push the view's frame down by 792 points for each page drawn already
    // and add it to the main view
    gridView.frame = NSMakeRect(0, 792 * i, gridView.frame.size.width, gridView.frame.size.height);
    [view addSubview:gridView];
}
```

I apologize if this is hard to understand for anybody; I'm better at talking through my process than writing! I welcome anyone to ask for help if there's something unclear, or edit if they can make it better.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [NSCollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCollectionView_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> Overview
>
> NSCollectionView class displays an array of content as a grid of
>   views. The views are specified using the NSCollectionViewItem class
>   which makes loadings nibs containing the view easy, and supports
>   bindings

There are lots of tutorials.
Including:

[Cocoa Programming L42 - NSCollectionView](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dw-sHMTsMVs)
And 
[Apples own quick guide to Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html)

And maybe also look at [NSDocuments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Overview
>
> The NSDocument abstract class defines the interface for OS X
>   documents. A document is an object that can internally represent data
>   displayed in a window and that can read data from and write data to a
>   file or file package. Documents create and manage one or more window
>   controllers and are in turn managed by a document controller.
>   Documents respond to first-responder action messages to save, revert,
>   and print their data.
>
> Conceptually, a document is a container for a body of information
>   identified by a name under which it is stored in a disk file. In this
>   sense, however, the document is not the same as the file but is an
>   object in memory that owns and manages the document data. In the
>   context of AppKit, a document is an instance of a custom NSDocument
>   subclass that knows how to represent internally, in one or more
>   formats, persistent data that is displayed in windows.
>
> A document can read that data from a file and write it to a file. It
>   is also the first-responder target for many menu commands related to
>   documents, such as Save, Revert, and Print. A document manages its
>   window’s edited status and is set up to perform undo and redo
>   operations. When a window is closing, the document is asked before the
>   window delegate to approve the closing.
>
> NSDocument is one of the triad of AppKit classes that establish an
>   architectural basis for document-based apps (the others being
>   NSDocumentController and NSWindowController).

Answer (score -1):

NsView; so tis a mac app?

CGPointMake Returns a point with the specified coordinates. i.e. placing an image in a specific spot on the screen using matrices i.e.

```
layer.position = CGPointMake ([self view].bounds.size.width /2, [self     view].bounds.size.height /3 );
```

(this example is oriented around core animation (moving objects on screen so please don't take it too literally) hence the layer attribute)

Also this line

```
layer.bounds= CGRectMake (100,100,1000,1000);
```

specifies a rectangles boundaries (rectangles can be filled with images and custom data using a bridge i believe; like this):

```
    UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"flogo@2x"ofType:@"png"]];

    layer.contents = (__bridge id)image2.CGImage;
```

Also i believe the cgdrawrect class when combined with matrices i.e. (x,x,x,x) can draw custom rectangles as in your image.

But hopefully you catch my drift with drawing and substituting images . The [Core graphics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreGraphics/Reference/CoreGraphics_Framework/_index.html) framework will probably be used here. ( my whole answer used [core animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) as a reference)